# Getting an exec format error on Linux (Chromebook)

Tags: chromebook, musescore

I've been trying to install the program Musescore on my chromebook. I have Linux installed and up and running. I'm able to get all the way to ./file step before I get an error.

```
./MuseScore-3.6.0.487916429-x86_64.AppImage: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I've looked at similar posts but none can seem to solve my problem. My laptop is 32 bit, the Linux is aarch64, the file is armhf. I've tried the same with both the 32 and 64 bit versions from musescore.org/download but nothing seems to work.

I have a suspicion it's something up with musescore's files but I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The file's *name* suggests its architecture is x86_64 ...

Comment: @steeldriver The name of the file is MuseScore-2.0.3-armhf.AppImage

Comment: Erm.. well that's not what the posted message says. Have you actually run the `file` command on it?

Comment: Apologies, I'm not familiar with Linux. I have run the file command. It says ELF 32-bit LSB executable. I'm not sure which version of the musescore software to download. There's the one in the post, a 32, and a 64. None work.

Comment: I see the aarch64 on my chromebook as well. I downloaded the arch version using the instructions I found here: https://community.masteringmusescore.com/c/education-resources/install-musescore-on-chromebook It's working for me. Happy scoring!

Answer (score 0):

Check which architecture you're using. The command `uname -m` should give you something like `x86_64`, `i686` or `arm64`. According to the [MuseScore homepage](https://musescore.org/en/download), there are MuseScore AppImage packages for `i686`, `x86_64` and `armhf`. The authors of MuseScore don't seem to offer AppImage packages for other architectures than those three.

Alternatively you can use the project's personal package archive (PPA). Check which exact version of Ubuntu you're using by looking for `DISTRIB_CODENAME` in the file `/etc/lsb-release`. This should be something like `bionic`, `focal` or `groovy`. Look at [the PPAs website](https://launchpad.net/%7Emscore-ubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/mscore-stable) whether it offers packages for your version. The available versions are listed in the "Published in" dropdown. If the PPA offers packages for your Ubuntu release, you can add the PPA to your repositories and install the package `musescore` as described on the PPAs homepage.

Comment: running the uname command shows aarch64 is the architecture, which would explain why they don't work. Is there a way to change the architecture of the Linux program from aarch64 to one of the ones listed above?

Comment: I'm also a little confused on the second paragraph. As mentioned above, I'm new to Linux. Could you run me through exactly what I need to do?

Comment: @n1njachikin "Is there a way to change the architecture of the Linux program" No, among other reasons because the architecture depends on your processor. That would be a bit like buying a car with an automatic transmission and ask whether the shop can change it to a stick shift ;)

Comment: @n1njachikin "Could you run me through exactly what I need to do?" In general it's expected in the Linux community to learn and understand what your doing. So I'd recommend you read up on PPAs, what they are and how to use them. It'll help you way more than typing commands that me or anybody whispers to you ;) Especially with installing software it can get quite dangerous to just blindly copy commands you found somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

From this link [MuseScore on Chromebook](https://community.masteringmusescore.com/c/education-resources/install-musescore-on-chromebook), in *littleccguy*'s [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1309390/getting-an-exec-format-error-on-linux-chromebook/1373974#comment2364414_1309390):

> #### Set up Linux
>
> (*Note: if you've already set up Linux, great! - but please also
> follow the instructions for sharing folders starting at step 5*)
>
> 1. Open your Chromebook settings (click the time at lower right of the shelf, then click the gear icon).
> 2. In the left panel, click "Advanced", then "Developers".
> 3. Next to "Linux development environment," select "Turn On" (if it is already turned on, skip to step 5).
> 4. Follow any additional prompts to set up Linux, which takes several minutes. For more information see [this support article on
>    google.com](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/9145439?hl=en), or search the web to see if there is anything more
>    recent.
> 5. Once the Linux setup is complete, open your regular "Files" app.
> 6. Right-click your "Google Drive / My Drive" folder.
> 7. If you see "Share with Linux", click it. If you see "Manage Linux sharing", it is already shared and you can skip this step.
>
> #### Download the MuseScore Installer for Chromebook
>
> (*Note: this only needs to be done once*)
>
> 1. Click this [link](https://community.masteringmusescore.com/c/education-resources/install-musescore-on-chromebook#downloadAttachment) to download the install-musescore script.
> 2. In the resulting dialog, navigate to your "Linux files" folder.
> 3. Click "Save".
>
> #### Install or Update MuseScore
>
> (*Do this to install or update MuseScore*)
>
> 1. Click the appropriate link below to download the current AppImage file (but first read the next two steps so you know where to save the
>    file):
>
>    - [Intel](https://musescore.org/en/download/musescore-x86_64.AppImage) (most mainstream Chromebooks)
>    - [ARM](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a4s5vD9dWo2WK1dwipxCfNtxFVjt6eyY/view?usp=sharing) (some smaller / tablet-based Chromebooks)
> 2. In the resulting dialog, navigate to your "Linux files" folder.
> 3. Click "Save".
> 4. Open the terminal window if it is not already open, by typing "terminal" into the launcher search bar and clicking the resulting
>    icon.
> 5. In the terminal window, type "sh install-musescore" (without the quotes) and then press "Enter". If this is an update of an existing
>    installation, you will be prompted to remove the previous version, and
>    you can go ahead and answer "Y" when asked.